# How to get the status of a stage on gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab pipeline similar to the below one

```
stages
  - test

p1::test:
stage: test
script:
  - echo " parallel 1"
p2::test:
stage: test
script:
  - echo " parallel 2"
p3::test:
stage: test
script:
  - echo " parallel 3"
p4::test:
stage: test
script:
  - echo " parallel 4"
```

All these four jobs will run in parallel, how can I get to know the status of the stage `test`,
I want to notify `Success` if all four are passed, `Failed` if anyone of the job fails.

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to tell if the prior stage (and everything before it) has passed or failed is to add another stage with two jobs that use opposite `when` keywords.

If a job has `when: on_success` (the default) it will only run if all prior jobs have succeeded (or if they failed but have `allow_failure: true`, or have `when: manual` and haven't run yet). If any job has failed, it will not.

If a job has `when: on_failure` it will run if any of the prior jobs has failed.

This can be useful for cleaning up build artifacts, or rolling back changes, but it can apply for your use case too. For example, you could use two jobs like this:

```
stages:
  - test
  - verify_tests

p1::test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo " parallel 1"

p2::test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo " parallel 2"

p3::test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo " parallel 3"

p4::test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo " parallel 4"

tests_passed:
  stage: verify_tests
  when: on_success # this is the default, so you could leave this off. I'm adding it for clarity
  script:
    - # do whatever you need to when the tests all pass

tests_failed:
  stage: verify_tests
  when: on_failure # this will only run if a job in a prior stage fails
  script:
    - # do whatever you need to when a job fails
```

You can do this for each of your stages if you need to know the status after each one programmatically.